# Auto Mailing using C# according to the time

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me to doing auto mailing using C# according to the time.

Comment: put some codes so that we can help you

Comment: What have you done so far? Please read [how to ask a good question on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: First, you need to create a service that will do the sending of email. Second, Create an executable like i.e. (.bat) file. Then run it through task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via 2 ways.

Either you write a code to send the mail & use a `windows scheduler` to send a mail at specific time interval.

Or if you dont want the dependency on windows, use `timer` in your C# code or an `unlimited loop` which runs for every second. Now in every loop counter check the time you need to send the mail & if matched, send the mail at that time.

Good Luck

Edit : Try something like this

```
while(true)
{
     if(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == "11:30:00")
     {
          // Send mail
     }
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: ok thank...can u give me a example of code in c# for try it.?..because i m really new for c# VB.net....thanks...

Answer (score 0):

For simple mailing application you can start with the follow links and expand as you want :

1. Use [Timer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer) for trigger every what time you want.
2. And use [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for send email.